# Pivot month from rows into columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to crosstab / pivot the data below

```
d = {'customer_code': ['A', 'B','A','C'], 
     'subscribe_date': ['2020-01-02', '2021-03-01','2020-01-02','2021-03-15'],
     'transaction_date':['2020-01-03','2021-03-02','2021-03-05','2021-03-17'],
     'sales':[50,30,20,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

to look like:

```
customer_code   subscribe_date  January_2020 February_2020 .... March_2021
0   A             2020-01-02              50            0      ....    20
1   B             2021-03-01               0            0      ....    30
3   C             2021-03-15               0            0      ....    10
```

where the transaction_date is transposed to row, and the cells are filled with the values from the `sales` column.

Using
`pd.crosstab(df['customer_code'], df['transaction_date'], dropna=False)`
, the `subscribe_date` is not involved in the new table. Also, I don't know how to specify the `sales` column into the `agg_func`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a combination of `pivot_table` and `strftime`

```
In [16]: pd.pivot_table(df, values='sales', index='customer_code', columns=df['transaction_date'].dt.
    ...: strftime('%B_%y'), aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
Out[16]: 
transaction_date  January_20  March_21
customer_code                         
A                         50        20
B                          0        30
C                          0        10
```

`pivot_table` in contrast to the easier `pivot` allows you to specify an aggregation function and fill values. The `values` argument says which values to aggregate and the `aggfunc` says how to aggregate.

Also to pivot you want to specify the customer code as the `index` and the extracted combination of month and year as `columns`. If the transaction_date is formatted as Datetime (`astype('datetime64[ns]')`), you can use the `strftime` API to convert that into basically every format you will ever need.

EDIT:
In your case of subsribe_date there is exactly one value for each customer. You can keep that be putting it into the index (redundantly)

```
In [97]: pd.pivot_table(df, values='sales', index=['customer_code', 'subscribe_date'], columns=df['tr
    ...: ansaction_date'].dt.strftime('%B_%y'), aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0).reset_index('subscribe_dat
    ...: e')
Out[97]: 
transaction_date subscribe_date  January_20  March_21
customer_code                                        
A                    2020-01-02          50        20
B                    2021-03-01           0        30
C                    2021-03-15           0        10
```

or (in my opinion the cleaner solution) separate it and join as needed

```
In [106]: customer = df[['customer_code', 'subscribe_date']].drop_duplicates()

In [107]: customer
Out[107]: 
  customer_code subscribe_date
0             A     2020-01-02
1             B     2021-03-01
3             C     2021-03-15


In [101]: transaction = pd.pivot_table(df, values='sales', index='customer_code', columns=df['transac
     ...: tion_date'].dt.strftime('%B_%y'), aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

In [102]: transaction
Out[102]: 
transaction_date  January_20  March_21
customer_code                         
A                         50        20
B                          0        30
C                          0        10

In [108]: customer.join(transaction, on='customer_code')
Out[108]: 
  customer_code subscribe_date  January_20  March_21
0             A     2020-01-02          50        20
1             B     2021-03-01           0        30
3             C     2021-03-15           0        10
```

I prefer the latter solution, because otherwise you would need to split off the subscribe_date again. every time you further process the transaction table (e.g to sum yearly values, calculate averages, etc.)

Comment: thank you @maow but how do I include the `subscribe_date` and potentially other columns into this pivot_table too?